# Convert spark streaming dataframe column value into new dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a nested json in one of the columns in a spark streaming dataframe. I would like to extract the column value, which is a json string, create a new data frame with it and write to a json file.

I want to do this without creating a schema for the json as schema can vary from document to document and is unknown.

I am using Scala

input dataframe

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|             raw data                |
+----------------+--------------------+
|{"key": "k1","value": "v1"}          |           
+----------------+--------------------+
```

desired output

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|   Key          |      value         |
+----------------+--------------------+
|   k1           |           v1       |  
+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-parse-json-from-text-file-string/ has examples of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If json already stored as struct, you can use something like

```
df.select("raw_data.*")
```

This will produce new dataframe with desired format

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It stored as string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('key', StringType(), True),
        StructField('value', StringType(), True)
    ]
)
df.withColumn("data", from_json("raw data", schema)).select(col('data.*')).show()
```